# Why 'executioner' and not 'executor'?

Tags: etymology

Doesn't 'executioner' seem like a roundabout way of naming someone who 'executes'?  I realize that it's a person who carries out 'executions', but it seems unnecessary to make a word that way if 'executor' already exists.  Is there a difference so that we can distinguish between someone who terminates criminals and someone who carries out a task?

Comment: Please consult a dictionary, where you will find that *executor* does mean 'someone who executes', but in a different, and more common, sense. You might also like to look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/).

Comment: Why practitioner, exhibitioner, resolutioner ?

Comment: @ermanen - I've never heard "resolutioner" before, and I doubt that I've heard "exhibitioner" except perhaps when someone was wanting to say "exhibitor" and misspoke.

Comment: @HotLicks: Now you've heard. *Exhibitioner* is a Brit term though.

Comment: @TimLymington I guess I really did just answer my own question.  Sorry to waste time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears that the poster didn't realize when posting the question that the word 'executor' is used to refer to someone who executes in a different sense that an executioner does.

Comment: Regarding all four of these words (_executioner_, _practitioner_, _exhibitioner_, _resolutioner_), The real question in my mind is: Were these words ending in _-tion_ (_execution_, etc.) ever used as verbs? That would be surprising to me. And if not, why was the _-er_ suffix applied to nouns when normally it is applied to verbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For execution, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execution says

> Specific sense of "act of putting to death" (mid-14c.) is from Middle
>   English legal phrases such as don execution of deth "carry out a
>   sentence of death."

For execute, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execute says

> Meaning "to inflict capital punishment" is from late 15c., from
>   earlier legal sense "perform judgment or sentence on" (early 15c.)

So, according to etymonline.com, execution meant "put to death/inflict capital punishment" over 100 years before execute did. Presumably the person who does it was named after the more traditional and, more importantly, more legal word for the act.

For executioner, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=executioner says

> "headsman," 1560s; "one who carries into effect," 1590s; agent noun
>   from execution. Old English words for it included flæscbana,
>   flæscwellere.

For executor, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=executor says

> c. 1300, "person appointed to see that a will is carried into effect,"

So it already had a very different meaning (and an important legal meaning at that). Perhaps then too the people who coined the word executioner for one who puts to death preferred not to overload executor instead.

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* finds that the first use of "execute" meaning to carry out a plan, instruction, or command in 1386 (from Chaucer, no less) and the first use of "executor" meaning the person who does the carrying out, two years later.   The first use of "execute" meaning to inflict capital punishment is found in 1483.  So the non-lethal meanings of "execute" and "executor" had almost a century's head start.  When it came time to find a word for the state's authorized killer, "executor" was taken.

Comment: This is the best answer. People give dictionaries way to much credit for being correct. Dictionaries blow with the wind of public mood. Clearly the verb that executor and executioner inherit from is execute. They would have needed a buzz word for a guy murdering on the Kings order, and if Executor was taken, then Executioner. They should have used Executor though.